# Why there is different private key for different service account of same firebase account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, verify

I need to generate jwt token for authentication and verify it.
and i am having different service accounts. Is it possible that i generate jwt token with 1 key and validate it with other for same firebase account

Answer (score 0):

To verify the JWT you must use the same key pair/credentials that were used to generate the JWT.

You can't use one key pair to generate the JWT, and then another key pair to verify it.